# Why does modifying a WordprocessingDocument that was opened from a Stream result in a corrupted file?

Tags: c#, .net, openxml

I'm using the `DocumentFormat.OpenXml` package to replace text in a `.docx` file. Got an issue with it, so started to do some investigations in order to get a deeper understanding of how `DocumentFormat.OpenXml` works. As result I got two C# methods, presented below:

**Code Sample 1**:

```
public static void SearchAndReplaceFile(string document)
{
    using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(document, true))
    {
        string docText = null;
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream()))
        {
            docText = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }

        Regex regexText = new Regex("Hello");
        docText = regexText.Replace(docText, "Good Evening");

        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream(FileMode.Create)))
        {
            sw.Write(docText);
        }
    }
}
```

**Code Sample 2**:

```
public static void SearchAndReplaceFileUsingStream(string document)
{
    Stream docStream = File.Open(document, FileMode.Open);
    using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(docStream, true))
    {
        string docText = null;
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream()))
        {
             docText = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }

        Regex regexText = new Regex("Hello");
        docText = regexText.Replace(docText, "Good Evening");

        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream(FileMode.Create)))
        {
            sw.Write(docText);
        }
    }
}
```

Both methods should replace "Hello" with "Good Evening" in the input `.docx` file, and based on my understanding, both should produce the same result. However, I actually got different results:

**Code Sample 1** - works correctly and result is as it was expected. "Hello" is replaced with "Good Evening" in the `.docx` file.

**Code Sample 2** - `.docx` file that I got as result of text replace looks corrupted. I can't open the updated `.docx` file via MS Word. Instead I get an error message:

[image: Word experienced an error trying to open the file.]

Another point I observed is that the resulting `.docx` files obtained via **Code Sample 1** and **Code Sample 2** have different sizes.

Can anybody explain why the result of **Code Sample 2** is incorrect and why it is not the same as for **Code Sample 1**? I don't want to burden you with too much detail, just to add that it is important for my task that the `WordprocessingDocument` object in **Code Sample 2** is obtained from a Stream but not directly from a file. So, I need to have **Code Sample 2** working properly and the `WordprocessingDocument` object must be obtained from a Stream in **Code Sample 2**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must close the Stream to ensure that buffered writes are flushed to the file. Change

```
Stream docStream = File.Open(document, FileMode.Open);
```

to

```
using (Stream docStream = File.Open(document, FileMode.Open))
```

or, if you're using C# 8.0 or later,

```
using Stream docStream = File.Open(document, FileMode.Open);
```